# За что отвечает media.autoplay.enabled в Firefox about:config режиме?

Tags: firefox, config

За что отвечает media.autoplay.enabled в Firefox about:config режиме ? О каком автопроигрывании речь ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он отключает автопроигрывание видео на Youtube и gifv, если *value* **true** преобразовать в **false** двойным щелчком.

*Круто ! Ато вечно мучилась с этими автоматическими запусками роликов.*

[Источник](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7awrz5/til_firefoxaboutconfigmediaautoplayenabledfalse/)